# I get several deprecation warnings printed, how to disable them?

Tags: plugin-system, lua

I see this when I open first file in nvim.
I have not much to do with these (those are plugins that I didn't write). How can I disable them being printed to console?

```
sumneko_lua is deprecated, use lua_ls instead.
This feature will be removed in lspconfig version 0.2.0
"plugged\LeaderF\autoload\leaderf\python\leaderf\lineExpl.py" 179L, 6936B
"plugged\LeaderF\autoload\leaderf\python\leaderf\lineExpl.py" 179 lines --36%--
vim.treesitter.query.get_node_text() is deprecated, use vim.treesitter.get_node_text() instead. :help deprecated
This feature will be removed in Nvim version 0.10
stack traceback:
    ...i\Neovim\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:274: in function 'get_node_text'
    ...gged\aerial.nvim/lua/aerial/backends/treesitter/init.lua:83: in function 'fetch_symbols'
    ...ni\.vim\plugged\aerial.nvim/lua/aerial/backends/init.lua:126: in function 'attach'
    ...ni\.vim\plugged\aerial.nvim/lua/aerial/backends/init.lua:142: in function 'get'
    ...ni\.vim\plugged\aerial.nvim/lua/aerial/backends/init.lua:226: in function 'attach'
    ...rni\.vim\plugged\aerial.nvim/lua/aerial/autocommands.lua:85: in function 'cb'
    vim/_editor.lua:263: in function <vim/_editor.lua:262>
```

Internally, it is a call to `vim.deprecated` in lua.

Comment: It seems that your lsp configuration make use of sumneko_lua to support the lua language server and it recommend you to use lua_ls instead. How are you managing the language server configuration? Are you using Mason?

Comment: I use lsp-config.